# simple php javascript countdown to DATETIME

Tags: php, timer, countdown

I have a DATETIME date in a mysql field, and i'd like the simplest timer displayed on my PHP page counting down to that. The timer will never be over a few minutes.

I'm guessing some kind of javascript php hybrid is needed?

Eg "40 secs left"

Note: I know nothing about javascript, but half decent at PHP.

Comment: To your deleted question: You have forgotten `$input = ` before your explode line :)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Keith Woord's jQuery [Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) plugin. It is very easy to use and you can pass it your DATETIME on page load via PHP echo / print.

I hope this helps!

EDIT:

To implement this solution you could do the following:

```
<head>
...

<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Activate Countdown //   
    $('timerDiv').countdown({ 
        until: new Date(<?= $date ?>), // Date need to be in "YYYY, Start - End, M" Format like this: "2012, 8 - 1, 8"
        format: 'HMS' // H = Hours, M = Minutes, S = Seconds. Remove letter to omit it
    });
</script>

...
</head>
<body>
    <div id="timerDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @user961882 is the DATETIME MySQL or Server based?

Comment: even the basics dont seem to work (that code above). I dont think my server supports new Date function or something. Im outta patience and energy lol I think i'll leave it.

Comment: @user961882 lol... been there. If there are specific errors that appear, or if you wanted to edit your OP with the code you are using, I'd be happy to take a look at it for you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) for that, so you just need to provide a date in correct format described there

Comment: ive got the countdown running, but i cant seem to get a php date converted into js for it. Ive checked all the tutorials and nothing makes sense or works for me. stressed lol