# Countdown inverted

Tags: javascript, php, html

anyone can help me? Example, I want a `countdown timer` but inverted, example:

I insert my date and hour in javascript or mysqL (doesn't matter) and it will count ..

Example: I inserted: 01/07/2015

today the counter will show: 1day 1hour 19min

Comment: I used this script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853179/simple-php-javascript-countdown-to-datetime

Comment: down inverted us usually called **up**

Comment: @thecreator so if you used that script whats your question

Comment: Because I want to change this, to "CountUP" instead `Countdown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use jquery then you can do something like this:

```js
var startTime = +new Date("07/01/2015"); // m/d/Y gets timestamp in ms

var second = 1000;
var minute = second * 60;
var hour = minute * 60;
var day = hour * 24;

var element = document.getElementById('timer'); // target element for the timer

function countUp() {
  // time between now and the start date
  var time = Date.now() - startTime;

  // days passed since start
  var days = Math.floor(time / day);
  time -= days * day;

  // hours passed
  var hours = Math.floor(time / hour);
  time -= hours * hour;

  // minutes passed
  var minutes = Math.floor(time / minute);

  // update element
  element.innerHTML = days + 'day ' + hours + 'hour ' + minutes + 'min';

  setTimeout(countUp, minute);
};

countUp();
```

```html
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use the jQuery Countdown plugin, you can just use it's built-in count up functionality. Take a look at the 'Count Up' tab of the jQuery Countdown page: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html.

EDIT: Adding code example

```js
$("#countdown").countdown({since: new Date(2015, 7-1, 1)});
```

```css
#countdown {
  float: left;
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://keith-wood.name/css/jquery.countdown.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>

<span id="countdown">
```